# jQuery Datatables keep selection after refresh

Tags: jquery, datatables

I created a Datatable, when clicking on a row, the row will be highlighted.

```
$("#example tbody").click(function(event) {
  $(eTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
     $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
  });

 $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');

});
```

The data in the table will be refreshed automatically

```
function refreshTable(table){
  eTable.fnReloadAjax(null, null, true);    
}           

function tableRefresher() {
    refreshTable(eTable);
    tid = setTimeout(tableRefresher, 1000); // repeat myself
}
```

After the table is refreshed, the selected row is not highlighted anymore.

Any ideas how to keep the selection intact after refreshing?

Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried this: eTable._fnAjaxUpdate(), it does make an ajax call but for some reason it does not update the table with the fetched data.

Comment: This might be worth looking at: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/reload.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone insterested,

this is more or less how I solved the problem

First store the hidden selected row id in a variable, selectedRowId

```
$('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
    var data = eTable.fnGetData(this);
    selectedRowId = data[4];
});
```

Refresh the table

```
refreshTable(eTable,'getAlerts');

function refreshTable(table, urlData)
{
  $.getJSON(urlData, null, function( json )
  {
    //table = $(tableId).dataTable();
    oSettings = table.fnSettings();
    table.fnClearTable(this);
    for (var i=0; i<json.aaData.length; i++)
    {
      table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
    }
    oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
    table.fnDraw();
    setSelectedRow();
  });
}
```

And re-selected the row after refresh

```
function setSelectedRow(){
    $(eTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
        var data = eTable.fnGetData(this.nTr);
        if(selectedRowId == data[4]){
            $(this.nTr).addClass('row_selected');   
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Since you have done essentially what I suggested, you could mark my answer as the 'accepted' one

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to have your `$("#example tbody").click()` event also store a cookie with the value of the row selected.

Then have your `refreshTable(table)` function, read the cookie, and re-add the `'row_selected'` class, after the ajax call returns successfully.

So --> table loads, user selects a row, row index is stored in cookie, table refreshes, cookie read, row re-selected.

Magic!

Comment: You could also try to have your refreshTable() function detect what row is selected before the ajax call, and after the ajax call re-set it.

Comment: Its only the data in the table that is refreshed, not the whole page. There is a hidden column with a unique value in every row in the table. So it should be possible to store the value of the hidden column for selected row, refresh the data, and then add the 'row_selected' class for the row with same hidden column value. The question is how to do that?

Comment: I've managed to find the unique id in the hidden column for the selected row like this:
`var selectedRowId;
$('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
 var data = eTable.fnGetData(this);
 selectedRowId = data[4];
});`
Now, how to find the corresponding row after table data refresh?